# How to git clone a local repository

Tags: linux, git, fedora

I have fedora 20 and I'm new to git - I followed a tutorial which guided me through setting up a user called 'git' and creating a bare repository in the home directory called test.git

Now I want to clone that repository as another user in my home directory, on the same server so that I can start pushing files to it.

If it's git clone...what address do I use?

Comment: Just use the path to the root directory of the bare repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cloning from the git home dir to my user home dir:

```
git clone -l ../git/test.git
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: ok added it even though I explained it in my opening question